# Set a bool value using model object didSet

Tags: swift, didset

I'm struggling to figure out how to properly set bool values using a model object's didSet. My app has a series of swipable cards where some flip and some don't. This code below is the CardView which is run for each card created.

Currently, the code works perfectly for the image and label—each card loads unique information based each card's model object. However, the button and isFlippable property are where I'm struggling.

The code right now is always loading the green pathway. The weird thing, however, is that even when the cardModel should sets the button isEnabled to false, it will still load the green (but the button won't work, so it did become disabled...)

```
var cardModel: CardModel! {
   didSet {
      imageView.image = cardModel.image
      label.text = cardModel.label
      flipButton.isEnabled = cardModel.isFlippable
      isBackShowing = cardModel.isFlippable //Intentionally use isFlippable here because I want the initial layout to be based on this true or false value.
   }
}


let imageView = UIImageView()
let label = UILabel()
let flipButton = UIButton()
var isBackShowing = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupLayout()
}

fileprivate func setupLayout() {

    if flipButton.isEnabled == true {
        if isBackShowing == true {
            backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            backgroundColor = .green
        }
    } else {
        backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}
```

I also have code for when the button flips that alternates "isBackShowing" and then calls setupLayout()—it is working fine. But it always loads as false during the initial setup of the card.

Comment: Where do you call `setupLayout `??

Comment: Sorry about that—tried to only include the relevant code and forgot that piece! I've added it now. I call it in ViewDidLoad, as well as each time the flip button is pressed (that part works fine, it's just the initial view that doesn't seem to wanna do what I want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better readability you can little bit update your code replacing `var isBackShowing = Bool()` by `var isBackShowing = false`.

And also you can call `setupLayout()` to update your layout after setting of cardModel. For example `didSet` of `cardModel` can looks like this:

```
var cardModel: CardModel! {
   didSet {
      imageView.image = cardModel.image
      label.text = cardModel.label
      flipButton.isEnabled = cardModel.isFlippable
      isBackShowing = cardModel.isFlippable
      setupLayout()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it and I understand it now. :) I'm new so this experience was a very good lesson in understanding didSet.